# Highcharts: keep a pie _sorted_

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to keep a pie chart *sorted* by decreasing values of its slices.

For example, if we start with a series: `[['foo', 4], ['bar', 2], ['baz', 1]]` and we receive an update telling us that the slice `bar` is now 8 units big, I would like to update the series as follows: `[['bar', 8], ['foo', 4], ['baz', 1]]`.

In the documentation I found two different methods handy for the problem: `series.setData` and `Point.update()`.  The problem with the former is that it doesn't trigger any animations:  it simply replaces the content of the series with the new set of points.  With the latter I am having troubles trying to keep the legend and the chart in sync:  http://jsfiddle.net/gnCSY/17/

Is there a way to update the legend once all the points of the charts have been updated?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this animations should look like (how to animate that one series grown more than another one). However, you can simple recreate chart, see: http://jsfiddle.net/gnCSY/19/

```
    if(chart)
        chart.destroy();
    options.series[0].data = new_data;
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Comment: When I say animation, I mean that each slice of the chart _slowly_ widens/narrows and changes its colour depending on the new array of data.  I already thought about destroying and recreating the chart from scratch but it seemed to me a bit _overkill_;  however, if that happens to be the more reasonable and appropriate solution for the problem I stick with that.